# Connect to Temenos T24 with Javascript or Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

We are using Temenos T24 as core banking platform. There are three layers in application:

1. front-end
2. REST API
3. T24.

REST API connects with T24 via TOCF and returns response in JSON format to front-end for T24 enquiry.

Is there anyway to connect to T24 using `nodejs` and get t24 message ?

Comment: How does your REST API connect via TOCF? Is it just a GET or POST request? Not sure if this helps: https://github.com/cowboy/node-toc

Answer (score 1):

You can execute node js script from t24 and get a response.

see below sample from jbase code

```
    PROGRAM TESTTEST

    Y.NODE = "node ./NODE.BP/test.js"
    EXECUTE Y.NODE CAPTURING Y.NODER
    CRT(Y.NODER)

    RETURN
END
```

NODE JS sample

```
var a=6;
var b=12;
var c=a+b;
/* var program_name1 = process.argv[0];
var program_name2 = process.argv[1];
var program_name3 = process.argv[2];
var program_name4 = process.argv[3];
console.log(program_name3)
console.log(program_name4)*/

console.log("Sum("+a+"+"+b+") is done in T24 and result is : "+c);
```

Answer (score 0):

ReST API does not connect to T24 via TOCF, its usage open source project IRIS and the only way to connect from nodejs to T24 is to use ReST API.

Namaste,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

you cannot connect to T24( business logics exposed via enquires and version to GUI) from your node.js. 
What you can do is either build node.js app that calls rest api to access  the functionality or you can connect to the database to get the data but your app should have the logic what should be done with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since R17 IRIS has been the common technology used to integrate T24 with external systems like GUIs. its expose the T24 functionalities into standard Api to be consumed by those system. there is another ways (Queues) but the most recommended and used is thru the Apis.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can build your nodejs app to connect using the rest endpoints configured in TAFJEE.ear for T24 in the application server (Now replaced with IRIS). NodeJs does this easily.